# Python `OS` package doesn't open files in order

Tags: python, python-os, listdir

I am trying to open bunch of `.tif` files and do some processing on them. I am using the following code to do this:

```
for images in os.listdir(folder_dir):
    if (images.endswith(".tif")):
        print(images)
```

The code works perfect; however, the only slight issue I have is that in one case, the files are not opened in order. See image below:

[image]

In the above example, it's clearly shown that picture #100 will be opened after picture #10. I expected to picture #100 will be opened after picture #99.

does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: The names are sorted lexicographically, not numerically.

Comment: Not even so. No order at all is guaranteed.

Comment: @Barmar any suggestion as how I can change the order to numerically?

Comment: See the question I linked to above.

Comment: "the files are not opened in order" why do you expect *any* order for `os.listdir`?

Comment: @Barmar although, in this case, something like `sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: int(re.search("\d+").group(0)))` would probably work